# API-Problem - POST Json-String with httpClient in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, dotnet-httpclient

I want to POST json values via httpClient into an API. Unfortunately I am quite a beginner and can't handle it.
GET works perfectly:
here the code for GET:

```
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader
    ' Wird für https-Requests benötigt
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072, SecurityProtocolType)

    request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim s As String
    s = reader.ReadToEnd
    Return s
```

But how do I realize POST?
My API-URL looks like this:
https://mydomaine.net/api/auth?token=467445892587458542...
an i will send an JSON-String {"test":"value1":"test1":"value2"}
I've been working on this problem for many hours.
Can someone please help ???

Comment: Set the `request.ContentType = "application/json"`, the `request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post` and write to the Request Stream (`request.GetRequestStream()`) the JSON as UTF-8 bytes, probably. Does this API have any documentation related to posting data? -- Why are you casting SecurityProtocolType to the `Tls12` Enum value? Are you still using a .Net Framework version prior to 4.5? Time to update.

Comment: I am extremely grateful for your help. I have a solution that works now.

Answer (score 1):

and here is the code that works

```
Public Function PostRequest(uri As Uri, jsonDataBytes As Byte(), contentType As String, method As String) As String
    Dim response As String
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

    request = WebRequest.Create(uri)
    request.ContentLength = jsonDataBytes.Length
    request.ContentType = contentType
    request.Method = method

    Using requestStream = request.GetRequestStream
        requestStream.Write(jsonDataBytes, 0, jsonDataBytes.Length)
        requestStream.Close()

        Using responseStream = request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
            Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
                response = reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return response
End Function
```

Comment: `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false`: your code is not handling the `100Continue` response from the server. You should also show how you're calling this method.